# Is there some way to check if mail was sent successfully in Shopware custom plugin?

Tags: shopware

Is there any function that does this?

I need some flag that will let me know if mail was not sent or connection to smtp server wasn't created.

Comment: If there is some way, it could be faked. So that way is not really reliable, notably w.r.t. malicious users. However, you could use some custom header in your mail message (e.g. SMTP)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. It all boils down to a problem of synchronicity. Mailing basically is networking and therefore inherently asynchronous, which means that a send mail will **eventually** arrive at its destination.

Theoretically all servers involved could send a response whether the mail arrived or not, but this is usually deactivated so spam bots can not guess valid email addresses.

The usual way to check if a mail arrived is to simply let the user click on a **confirmation link** and log it yourself.